After WSL install or enable subsystem for linux windows , if I restart my laptop. The system stuck on a black screen
I want to install docker on my fresh installed windows 11 pro. But , when I install wsl 2 buy run this command
wsl —install 

on powershell as an administrator and restart my computer. My computer restart and stuck on a black screen. If i try to restart again, it shows ‘diagnosing your pc’.
I tried different ways of installing, without run
wsl —install

this command, I tried by enabling windows subsystem for linux , then go for restart & same thing happened . System stuck on black screen.
Note that, without restart as soon as i installed docker desktop and go for restart, same things happened.
I am Using Asus Tuf gaming FX505-DT Laptop

Did you make sure you enabled virtualization on your BIOS?

I checked task manager > cpu & found virtualization enabled. Should i check from Bios too?

You can if you want to for good measure. also you can to uninstall it, update all drivers and all the widows security updates... them do another clean install of wsl and make sure wsl --set-default-version 2.. then install docker again and make sure WSL 2 based engine is selected.
